# Mysql_result .. not showing data

Tags: php

```
function getfield($get){
    global $connection;

$query = "SELECT id, username, firstname, lastname FROM users WHERE username='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'";
        if ($query_r = mysqli_query($connection, $query)) {
            $num_rows = ($query_r -> num_rows);
            if ($mysqli_result = mysqli_result($query_r, 0, $get)) {
                return $mysqli_result;
            }
```

I made a log in form and now all working fine but this function don't showing data. I think `mysql_result` not working in 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getfield($get){
global $connection;
session_start();
$query = "SELECT id, username, firstname, lastname FROM users WHERE username='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'"; 
if ($query_r = mysqli_query($connection, $query)) { 
$num_rows = ($query_r -> num_rows); 
if ($mysqli_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_r)) { 
return $mysqli_result; 
}
}
```

Comment: What has changed here?

Answer (score 0):

The function `mysqli_result` does not exist, so you would need to use something like `mysqli_fetch_array()`. Replace your innermost `if`-clause with this:

```
if ($mysqli_result = mysqli_fetch_array($query_r)) { 
  return $mysqli_result[$get];
}
```